# "Spam report" meaning in Sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, spam, email-spam

I am using Sendgrid statistics on my emails and would like to understand correctly the meaning of "Spam report" event.

According to their documentation, "Spam Reports are triggered when a customer clicks the spam button or puts your email in their spam folder within their email client"

I understand that there can be two different events connected with spam:

- a customer clicks the spam button on an email or puts it into spam folder
- an email is filtered into the spam folder by the receiving mail server

My question is: does the "Spam report" event in Sendgrid include both these cases or just the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SendGrid's Spam Reports are only if a user has actively clicked "this message is Spam", on one of the providers who report that information back to SendGrid, such as Yahoo. On the other hand, Gmail, for example, does not report that information back, so those will never show up as a Spam Report.

The automatic filtering that you're referring do in the second event is called "Bulking" in the email world and does not have the negative deliverability impact that a recipient actively marking your message as Spam does, it just reduces the likelihood of engagement.